# docker-compose up postgresql error, chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgresql-9.6

I'm working on a project were we use docker with postgresql. I'm trying to start the docker container with `sudo docker-compose up`, but everytime it gives me this error:

`eurofins-database_1  | chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted`.

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
services:
  eurofins-database:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - ../eurofins-database/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

When I check the status with `docker ps` it shows me

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
9cc0f277c095        postgres:9.6-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 minutes ago      Restarting (1) 7 seconds ago                       local-postgres_eurofins-database_1
```

that a container is running (but obviously not properly).

**EDIT:**

Output of `ls -l ../eurofins-database`:

`drwxrwxrwx 1 max max 4096 Mär 17 10:10 data`

Output of `ls -l ../eurofins-database/data`:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 18:53 base
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max  8192 Mär  5 10:52 global
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 10:52 pg_clog
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 10:52 pg_commit_ts
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär 17 10:10 pgdata
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 10:52 pg_dynshmem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 max max  4478 Mär  5 18:53 pg_hba.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 max max  1636 Mär  5 18:53 pg_ident.conf
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 18:53 pg_logical
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 10:52 pg_multixact
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 10:52 pg_notify
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 18:53 pg_replslot
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 10:52 pg_serial
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 10:52 pg_snapshots
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 18:53 pg_stat
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 18:53 pg_stat_tmp
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 10:52 pg_subtrans
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 18:53 pg_tblspc
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max     0 Mär  5 10:52 pg_twophase
-rwxrwxrwx 1 max max     4 Mär  5 18:53 PG_VERSION
drwxrwxrwx 1 max max 12288 Mär  9 09:43 pg_xlog
-rwxrwxrwx 1 max max    88 Mär  5 18:53 postgresql.auto.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 max max 22471 Mär  5 18:53 postgresql.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 max max    24 Mär  5 18:53 postmaster.opts
-rwxrwxrwx 1 max max    85 Mär  5 18:53 postmaster.pid
```

Also I'm using `Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia` as host OS.

I'm very new to docker and I looked up several other posts, but couldn't find anything that fixes my problem.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you post `ls -l` for `../eurofins-database/` and `../eurofins-database/data`? I'm assuming you're using Docker for Mac and it could be something _wrong_ with the permissions for the directory you are trying to bind mount into the container.

Comment: I added the info in my post. I'm using Linux Mint.

Comment: What happens if you remove `PG_DATA` from `environment` in compose file? There could be some issue because you put the same value as the default one and not as the subdirectory, e.g. `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata`.

Comment: It's still the same output. Seems that it had no effect at all.

Comment: It seems to me that your local files are owned by user `max` and PostgreSQL requires user `postgres`. Did you already have those files or were they created by the container?

Comment: I got the data like this. I inspected the problem with a colleague of mine and he also suggested that it has to do with the ownership of the files. I tried to change the user, but my system won't let me.

Comment: Perhaps you can change UID and GID for the user that owns those files to match the PostgreSQL user. After all, permissions and ownerships in Linux are just numbers. :)

Comment: I found another solution. The data is on an external HDD with file system ```Fuse```. Stated in this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389991, Fuse is a non-Unix file system without support for Unix permissions. I backed up my data and formated the HDD to ```ext4```. Now it works.